# Error in TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, react-props

I'm trying to create a click event be able to delete an item on my list, but when I click it I get "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')".

and I'm pretty sure it's something to do bind 'this' somewhere, but I've tried a lot of places and it doesn't work.
[image]

here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";

import { userProfile } from "../recoil";
import ProfileName from "./components/profileName";

const DetailProfil = () => {
  const profile = useRecoilValue(userProfile);

  return (
    <div>
      <ProfileName
        profilePicture={profile?.profilePicture}
        fullName={profile?.fullname}
        roleDetails={profile?.details.name}
      />

      
    </div>
  );
};

export default DetailProfil;
```

Comment: `details` is `undefined`

Comment: Because `profile` may not be defined _at that point_ its stands to reason that `details` doesn't either. So that should alsoo be checked too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the optional operator to details object too

```
roleDetails={profile?.details?.name}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)

```
roleDetails={profile?.details?.name ?? 'YOUR_DEFAULT_ROLE_HERE'}
```